# How to fix 403 error when creating GoogleFit datasource

Tags: ios, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-fit, google-fit-api

I am using [GoogleFit Rest API](https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/add-nutrition-data#rest) to create a nutrition data source so that I can subsequently store nutrition information. I have done this successfully on Android via the GoogleFit SDK, but because no such SDK is available on iOS, I resorted to using the REST APIs via the link above. When trying to create the data source I am returned the following error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "The caller does not have permission",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

and the **POST** request I am using is:

Endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources

Body:

```json
{
    "application": {
        "detailsUrl": "https://strongfoundation.dev",
        "name": "Strong Foundation",
        "packageName": "com.coding.casa.Strong.Foundation",
        "version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "dataStreamId": "raw:com.google.nutrition:com.coding.casa.Strong.Foundation:Apple:iPad Air (3rd generation):****",
    "dataType": {
        "name": "com.google.nutrition"
    },
    "device": {
        "manufacturer": "Apple",
        "model": "iPad Air (3rd generation)",
        "type": "phone",
        "uid": "*****",
        "version": "15.7"
    },
    "name": "strong-foundation-food",
    "type": "raw"
}
```

Has anyone seen this error and was able to resolve it? I have tried adding the API Key to the request, but that did not change the error, and I do have the Fitness API enabled on my project.

EDIT:

I am also supplying a Bearer token with the following authorized scopes

```
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.write",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.read",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.nutrition.read",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.nutrition.write",
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't include the others details of the REST method call.

Importantly, HTTP 403 is Forbidden suggesting that you didn't include an `Authorization` header in your request with value `Bearer {TOKEN}` where `{TOKEN}` is an access token for an identity that has suitable scopes to access the API. See [authorization](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/authorization)

Although Swift is not one of Google's officially supported languages, Google has a [Swift REST Client Generator for Google APIs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-swift-client) and you should be able to use it to generate a Google client library for Swift for Google Fit.

Comment: Google Rest APIs return a 401 when missing the auth token. But the request is being sent with proper auth

Comment: Thanks for this lib, it didnt solve my problem per say but will definitely be a good guide in the future

Answer (score 0):

Did some more playing around with the FitnessAPI (specifically creating data sources) and found the issues was with my request payload.

The payload that worked for me is as follows:

```json
{
    "application": {
        "detailsUrl": "https://strongfoundation.dev",
        "name": "Strong Foundation",
        "version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "dataType": {
        "name": "com.google.nutrition"
    },
    "device": {
        "manufacturer": "Apple",
        "model": "iPad Air (3rd generation)",
        "type": "phone",
        "uid": "****",
        "version": "15.7"
    },
    "name": "strong-foundation-food",
    "type": "raw"
}
```

The deltas from the original one are removed the following properties:

- application.packageName
- dataStreamId